# Do I need a transit visa for a layover in Kuala Lumpur?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, malaysia, kul

I am an Indian who is planning to travel to Vietnam in January 2018. I am travelling with Air Asia from Mumbai with a layover in Kuala Lumpur for 5 hours. Do I need a transit visa for this? The flights from both destinations (BOM-KUL and KUL-SGN) are with Air Asia.

Answer (score 3):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Malaysia#Transit

If you're not

> holding a visa or a residence permit issued by Australia, China, Japan, New Zealand, South Korea, Taiwan or the United States, and are departing to or arriving from these countries.

Then you'll need a transit visa.

Comment: You missed `Nationals of other non visa-exempt countries can transit through Kuala Lumpur International Airport for a maximum of 24 hours, however they are not permitted to switch between the main terminal and KLIA2 unless they hold a valid visa`. Timatic also says the same.

Comment: but I am not going out of the airport

Answer (score 0):

Timatic says:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> - Nationals of Bangladesh, India, Pakistan and Sri Lanka who reside in country of nationality transiting through Kuala Lumpur (KUL) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must:
>
>   - arrive at and depart from the same terminal, and
>   - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
>   - have documents required for the next destination.

Comment: Welcome to Travel! I've edited out your question, because this is posted as an answer; please take a moment to read the [tour] – you'll notice we're a Q&A site and not a discussion forum.